# elementor plugin right space

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm building a landing page on my wordpress site using elementor, after creating the page i noticed i have extra space on the right side when i slide the horizontal navigation, i need to get rid of that please how do i do this.

I have tried to stretch all the pages from the layout settings from the visual builder but still no improvement.
I also tried using some custom CSS still to nothing

This only occurs on the pages i created with elementor please help me fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the site?

Comment: here's the link: [link] leftistarts@gmail.com

Comment: Umm... that's an email address.

Comment: so sorry about that i was absent minded leftistarts.com